# React Native Text component will not center inside a View component

Tags: ios, text, view, center, react-native

Hi I think this should be simple, but I cannot get it to work. Seems like no matter what I do, I cannot get the text component to center horizontally inside the view. I have tried using alignItems:center, justifyContent:center, alignSelf:center, textAlign:center... nothing works. I can get it to center vertically, but not horizontally. Whyyyyy dear lord?

```
<Animated.View style={[styles.titleContainer]}>
    <Text style={styles.title}>App logo here</Text>
</Animated.View>
```

How can I get the text to center both vertically and horizontally?

Here is my CSS:

```
titleContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop:30,
    marginBottom:30,
    justifyContent:'center'
},
title:{
    color:'white',
    textAlign:'center',
    alignSelf:'center'
},
```

This is my result:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Try this...
Here's a [working demo](https://rnplay.org/apps/jF6wIQ)

```
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 30,
    marginBottom: 30,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 28,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone looking for a minimal version for the simplest case:

```js
<View style={styles.containerView}>
  <Text style={styles.centeredText}>I'm centered</Text>
</View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  containerView: {
    justifyContent: 'center'
  }
  centeredText: {
    alignSelf: 'center'
  }
})
```

[Align Self](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flexbox#align-self)

Answer (score 1):

Add `justifyContent: 'center'` to the container view.
React native works different to react.
So alignItems not working, instead justifyContent works.

Answer (score 1):

use  `textAlign: 'center'` property to center text

use `alignSelf:'center'` property to center View

```
<View style={{alignSelf:'center'}}>

      <Text style={{textAlign:'center'}}>I'm centered</Text>

</View>
```

Answer (score 1):

set in main View style `flex:1` and in Text set `textAlign:'center'`

Answer (score 0):

Adding `flexDirection:'column'` helps the items to be aligned centrally column by column:

```
titleContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop:30,
    marginBottom:30,
    justifyContent:'center',
},
title:{
    color:'white',
    textAlign:'center',
    alignSelf:'center',
    flexDirection: 'column'
},
```

Comment: In React Native `flexDirection` is `column` by default.